# UITextField not working in UIView.animateDuration in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

This is iPad app by using SWIFT. It having two views. 
1. starting_View
2. login_View
These two views are in same ViewController. 
starting_View will be first view. By Clicking, NEXT button in first View, Starting View will move to left side by using animateDuration and same time, login_View will come from right. If we click Username/password fields (Any TextField), it will navigates to previous view.

Same time,,

if login_View will be first screen means, textField is working, keyboard is appearing.
But in animateDuration, i couldn't type. Kindly help me. Am using XCODE 6.1.

**Code (from comment):**

```
@IBAction func getStart_button(sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0.25, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.clt_login_vw.frame = CGRectMake(450, 56, 574, 660)  
    }, completion:nil)
}
```

Comment: try after disabling autolayout on your ViewController. You can disable easily on Interface Builder.

Comment: also show your code.

Comment: @IBAction func getStart_button(sender: UIButton) { 
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0.25, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {self.clt_login_vw.frame = CGRectMake(450, 56, 574, 660)
 }, completion:nil)
}

Comment: without auto layout, it is working fine. But if i need to add constraints means, how can i? @bpolat

Comment: hi @bpolat! any idea??

Comment: Try to use this method discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296232/ios-how-does-one-animate-to-new-autolayout-constraint-height/26040569#26040569

Answer (score -1):

In General try to never change frames directly when using Autolayout.
The best way to move views have been for me to use CGAffineTransform.

```
let move = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(translation_X , translation_Y)
```

and inside your animation closure:

```
self.clt_login_vw.transform = move
```

Then to return it back just do inside the animation Closure:

```
self.clt_login_vw.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
```

Resume:

```
let moveOut = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(translation_X , translation_Y)

@IBAction func getStart_button(sender: UIButton) { 
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0.25, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
           [weak self] // Remember no not create cycles

            self!.clt_login_vw.transform = moveOut 

        }, completion:nil)
    }
```

Edit:

Im gonna add Noah Witherspoon's option.
Another way to do this is getting the constraint that is holding your view horizontally, once you get it, you change its constant and call layoutIfNeeded() inside the closure:

```
@IBAction func getStart_button(sender: UIButton) { 

     constraint.constant = newConstant // enough to make it off the screen 

     UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0.25, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
               [weak self] // Remember no not create cycles

                self!.view.layoutIfNeeded()

            }, completion:nil)
 }
```

The way to get the specific constraint, I'm more friend of making IBOutlets, so I get easily its reference in Code.

That is if you didn't make it by code.

Comment: Setting a transform is also the wrong way to go about this — to animate views using constraint-based layout, you should be changing the properties of the constraints.

Comment: I wouldn`t say is wrong, but an option, Anyway you are right that animating constraints constant changes would be the best

Comment: Hi all! My Query. If Controller is in AUTO LAYOUT, Textfield is working when we simply view gets loaded. But, if we moving the view using animate Duration, at that time TextField is not working. If we click the field, automatically navigates to previous view..    If controller is not in AUTO LAYOUT, Textfield is working when view gets loaded as well as in animateDuration.

Comment: Hey, as we said, the problem most probably is the way you are moving the view. To avoid autolayour problems, don't move frames directly, instead, change the auto layout constants, or use transformations to move the view as I tried to explain above.