# How can I animate any UIView inside UITableViewCell?

Tags: animation, uitableview

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20.0, 20.0, 15.0, 15.0))
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.flamingoColor() 

UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: {
    cell.addSubview(label)
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
})
```

This code I put inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` -> result is a subview that has a yellow background, but I haven't seen any animation. The same is for method `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:`

Which method should I use or what kind of animation should I put there to see any animations inside UITableViewCell. I know that I **cannot** animate existing labels, because these are with constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should move `cell.addSubview(label)` to outside of the animation block and add the label to the `contentView` of the cell.

Back to your problem. You can't animate the background colour of a UILabel. You could use a UIView, of the same size, behind the UILabel for the same effect though.

To get the UIView to change colour once it's appeared I used a UITableViewCell subclass:

```
class AnimatedCell : UITableViewCell {
    let animatedView = UIView()

    /*  Setup by adding animatedView to the contentView and setting the 
        animated view's initial frame and colour.
    */

    func animate() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0) {
            animatedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() 
        }
    }
```

Then in your `UITableViewController` subclass, when the view controller is presented the `UITableView` will be populated so you need to animate those cells with:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)

    for cell in tableView.visibleCells() as! [UITableViewCell] {
        if let animatedCell = cell as? AnimatedCell {
            animatedCell.animate()
        }
    }
}
```

Then, for cells that appear when you scroll:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let animatedCell = cell as? AnimatedCell {
        a.animateLabel()
    }
}
```

Also, you can animate with AutoLayout, you need to change the `constant` on the `NSLayoutConstraint` you want to animate. This gives a good example: [iOS: How does one animate to new autolayout constraint (height)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296232/ios-how-does-one-animate-to-new-autolayout-constraint-height)