# how to animate an existing button in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like to animate an existing UIButton in swift, the goal is to let get the attention of the user to this button when he taps the view controller. The animation is supposed to start from the top in the view controller and go to the initial position of the button.

I did the following scenario but it's not working:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var dismissButton: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dismissButton = UIButton()

    var tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTapGesture:"))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

}



func handleTapGesture(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    println("tap")

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0.5, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: nil, animations: {

        self.dismissButton.center = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 90 + 200)
        }, completion: nil)
}


}
```

Any suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: But where you want to end the animation?

Comment: Whats the issue now?

Comment: I edited the question to explain the problem better. Thank you

Comment: Have you used autolayout?

Comment: Yes i used Autolayout

Comment: Ok, so changing frame don't work. You need to update you constraint's constant and then call self.view.layoutIfNeeded() in animation block.
Here is an example : http://kingscocoa.com/tutorials/autolayout-animations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** Take `IBOutlet` of your Top Constraint of button
**Step 2:** Update your Constraint's constant by using constraintName.constant property
**Step 3:** In animation block type `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`

Here is an simple example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26040569/3411787