# IOS: Hide/Reload tableView header

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, tableview

I created header for tableview(!not for the section) in story board with auto layout.

I want to have ability to show/hide it.

How can I do it?

I tried this code:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView.hidden = !flag;

CGRect frame = self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame;
frame.size.height = flag? k_HEIGHT_TableViewHeader : 0;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame = frame;
```

It works , But it gives me a lot of auto layout errors.

Also I can set it to nil. If so, how can I load header from storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [tableview reloadData] when you decide to hide/ show?

Comment: yes, it hide/show it but if it hides the frame did not changes, so I have clear space instead my header

Comment: at that point you would want to do the code to move your tableview back to the top.  This can be done by making an IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint and connecting it to your 'top space to Superview' constraint.  Update that topConstraint to 0 when you hide and whatever you need to (like 30 pixels) when you show.

Answer (score 0):

Because you created it with auto layout, rather than changing the frame, you should link the constraint for the height on your `tableHeaderView` from the storyboard to your class. Then when you want to collapse it, set the `constraint.constant = 0` and expand it again by setting `constraint.constant = k_HEIGHT_TableViewHeader`. You will need to call `layoutIfNeeded` on the view afterwards as well.

This change can also be easily animated by wrapping the `layoutIfNeeded` in a UIView animation block

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{[self.view layoutIfNeeded];}];
```

[Auto Layout Animation Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296232/ios-how-does-one-animate-to-new-autolayout-constraint-height)

Comment: Yes, but it not possible to add height constraint to tableView's header in storyboard