# iOS: Animation does not do what is intended

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm doing an incredibly simple animation. I'm just moving a button down.

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) { () -> Void in
        self.backButton.center.y += 30.0
    }
```

From my understanding, and what I've read of other answers to similar questions this should be all it takes.

But what instead happens, the button teleports (for lack of a better word) **up** 30 and then animates back to the original position. I've been tearing out my hair at this little problem. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: On iOS, the coordinate system is such that positive y is down on the screen.  So if the up you are referring to is up on the screen, then the center's y value must have decreased in value.  Did you subtract from center.y prior to the animation?

Comment: @ConspicuousGuy, when I added print statements it didn't indicate anything like that was happening.

Comment: So the self.backButton.center.y += 30.0 is the only time self.backButton.center.y or anything relating to the y position of the backButton is altered?

Comment: @SwiftMatt, in the viewDidLoad method I added constraints to the button. That would be the only time it's position is altered.

Comment: Well it sounds like the animation is going down as you want it to, but something is moving the button UP before the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after banging my head against a wall for a bit, I realized that layout constraints were causing the issue. I was looking at outdated questions.

Here's the workaround: [iOS: How does one animate to new autolayout constraint (height)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296232/ios-how-does-one-animate-to-new-autolayout-constraint-height)