# iOS 7 animation block not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, uiviewanimation, ios7

I have the following code to animation some view in my app:

```
void (^animate)() = ^() {
    CGRect leftFrame = centerFrame;
    leftFrame.origin.x -= centerFrame.size.width;
    newViewController.view.frame = centerFrame;
    oldViewController.view.frame = leftFrame;
};

if (animated) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:nil
                     animations:animate
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
} else {
    animate();
}
```

This animates correctly on iOS 6, however on iOS 7 there is no animation. Oddly the code inside the block does get called and the view does update, just without the animation duration taken into account.

Is there a reason why this block isn't getting called?

Comment: It's working for me on both the device and simulator – what does your animate block look like?

Comment: This is so weird. About 1/3 of the time I run the app it works. The rest of the time it does not perform the block with animation.

Comment: @AshFurrow I've updated the code example. It's definitely not just this block, several places it doesn't perform the animations from blocks that have been defined. And it's consistent throughout the app: either it does animate anything defined in blocks or it does not.

Comment: I'm making a wild guess in the dark, but are both view controllers part of the view hierarchy at the time you apply the animations? Is there any variation in whether they're part of the view hierarchy?

Comment: @Tommy Yes, both are part of the view hierarchy as they're the one's being animated.

Comment: Same issue here. My log inside is showing - but no animation happens.

Comment: And what is the original state of those two views, is it possible that one view is on top of the other, and hide the animation underneath)

Comment: Hi @runmad, it is happening the same thing to my app. It happens with ALL the animations of the app (executed when showing controller, after pressing a button, etc, that is, in every kind of situation), but it happens only sometimes, and after playing a while with the app, animations then stop animating, and just place the views in the final state. Soooooo weird.

Comment: @Monitus Yeah, I can't quite figure it out. Doesn't seem to be an issue with apps that are built from scratch in Xcode 5/iOS 7.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue: an animation block that works like a charm in iOS6 is executed without the animation in iOS7.

Not sure if this might help you but I moved the animation trigger to `viewDidAppear:` and now its being animated.

So for you this might look like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    animate();
    // do your other stuff here...
}
```

Comment: Worked for me. My code was previously in viewDidLoad, in a UIViewController being pushed to the screen.

Comment: But I am not doing the animations in `viewDidLoad:` it's a parent view controller that handles the animations for the child view controller's views.

Answer (score 2):

Your animation may be colliding with another competing animation block, perhaps one called by UIKit during a transition. Instead of passing `nil` to the animation options, use:

`UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedOptions | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState`

and see if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same regression between iOS6 and iOS7.

In my case, it was due to the fact that `animateWithDuration:` was called before the `UIView` it animates appeared on screen.

In iOS7 it appears that you shouldn't call `animateWithDuration:` before `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` is called on the controlling `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. What it turned out for me is I needed to reference a different part of the UITableViewCell I was animating than I did with iOS 6. It might be a similar issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably autolayout in iOS 7 which is giving you troubles. I just had the same problem. Instead of animating the frame, you need to animate the constraints.

See [Are NSLayoutConstraints animatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926566/are-nslayoutconstraints-animatable) for how to do it.

Comment: I am not using auto layout, though.

Answer (score 0):

try using :

[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];