# NSLayoutConstraint animation duration in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, animation, ios7, duration, nslayoutconstraint

I cannot figure out how to set NSLayoutConstraint animation duration in iOS7. Here's my code:

```c
self.loadingViewTop.constant = -[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
self.loadingViewBottom.constant = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;

[UIView animateWithDuration:30.0f animations:^{
    [self.loadingView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are NSLayoutConstraints animatable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926566/are-nslayoutconstraints-animatable)

Comment: @iiFreeman I tried it. Actually if you remove [UIView animateWithDuration] code the view still animates. I cannot see any possible solution how to control it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh you forget to call `[self.view layoutIfNeeded];` inside animation block

Comment: I tried it as well. It does not make any difference. I think layout constraints behave differently in iOS7. Code which worked well in iOS6 does not work any more.

Comment: did you check your constants are actually not nil?

Comment: Ok I got it working. Here's the right way of doing it:

self.loadingViewTop.constant = -[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
self.loadingViewBottom.constant = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;

[UIView animateWithDuration:30.0f animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

```
self.loadingViewTop.constant = -[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
self.loadingViewBottom.constant = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;

[UIView animateWithDuration:30.0f animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```