# UITableView Auto-Layout Flexible Height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have following design.
[image]

Am using `AutoLayout` to make every thing flexible. In this design i have a `UIView` which is Gray in Color as showing in image and a `UITableView` below `UIView`. Some times i have to show this `UIView` and some times i have to hide this Gray `UIView`.

My problem is when ever i hide `UIView`, `UITableView` is not fixing its height. I don't want to hard code in .m file. Is it possible `AutoLayout` take care of this issue. I have these constraints as below image. Am i missing any constrain.

[image]

When i try to change `UIView` height, UITableView is not moving up and showing some orange constraints as show in image.
[image]

Comment: Did you check in runtime? In interface builder, if you changed a constant of constraints, it show a orange yellow line to inform that layout of relative view will be changed in runtime. Just you want to remove yellow line in interface builder, select editor-> resolve auto layout issues -> update frame..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contraints looks good. All you have to do to show/hide the gray `UIView` is change the height constraint constant.
To do this, create an `IBOutlet` in your controller for the constraint (you do this the same way you would for a `UIView` `IBOutlet`), and when you want to hide the gray view, set the `constant` property of the constraint to `0`.

eg.

```
@interface MyViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *greyViewHeightConstraint;
@end
```

and when you want to hide the view:

```
self.greyViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0;
```

To show the view again, you would have to save the "default" constant value after the storyboard is loaded (like in `viewDidLoad` for example), and set `self.greyViewHeightConstraint.constant` to this saved value.

Note also that these constraint changes [can be animated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926566/are-nslayoutconstraints-animatable).

---

The "orange constraint" you are seeing in Interface Builder is normal: it indicates that the view frame is not matching the constraints you set. You can then update the frame to respect the constraints, or update the constraints to match the frame.

Comment: Ok. Let me try your solution.